# Mono Pkg-Config.exe Keeps Crashing?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, pkg-config

I'm new to Mono - thought I'd give cross platform a try - my main IDE is Visual Studio and so the process of building applications through the command prompt is a bit foreign to me.

I was following the [Mono Basics](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) tutorial, and have gotten to the point where it says **Winforms Hello World**. I copied the code provided and saved it to a .cs file (on the Desktop).

I then opened up a command prompt and pointed it towards the Desktop directory. I ran the command:

```
mcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet
```

And the result was:
[image: Pkg-Config.exe not working]

The console told me that it was a CS8027 error but nothing else.

I have 3 environment variables that I added, with no fix:

- PATH -> path to mono\bin
- PATH -> path to mono\lib\pkgconfig
- PKG_CONFIG_PATH -> path to mono\lib\pkgconfig

This happens whenever I try to use pkg-config.exe (tried to use pkg-config.exe --list-all but the same problem arose).

I've checked other answers/questions about the CS8027 error but the solutions did not help - it *still* crashes every time!

Comment: you fixed that problem? I'm have the same issue nowadays. First was problem on GTK# and messy with PATH dlls (completly hell), now this is fixed I got pkg-config crashes... :(

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.  I had all the proper VC++ runtimes installed, but still crashed.

pkg-config.exe references librares (.dll) that are compiled in different versions of .Net. Your PATH (or pkg-config itself) might be referencing a different version than the one the .dll uses, or not have it at all.

pkg-config is a short-hand anyway.  I fixed it by explicitly including the .dll I'm referencing using the proper version of .Net for me:

```
mcs hello.cs -r:"C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\4.5-api\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

pkg-config is built with a different version of MSVC to Mono itself. You need the 32-bit VC++12 runtime installed for it to work. That *ought* to be included with mono.msi, as per https://github.com/mono/release/commit/8394dcc254510977c3e654abf916a48c6c6894fb

If you check the Windows event log, under Applications, you might get more information on what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, could help some.

```
D:\Code\Mono>mcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.
```

I needed to download the following DLL:s from https://www.dll-files.com/

- libiconv-2.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
- libintl-8.dll
- libglib-2.0-0.dll

Put them in C:\Program Files\Mono\bin

All DLLs should be 32 bits even if Mono was 64 bits.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the DLL's but didn't realize they needed to be 32-bit, that worked for me :)

Comment: downloading dll's to fix issues is the worst possible advice you can give - it's as good as throwing out your bank account to the wolves to feast on. Either download from trusted sources with signed install or build it yourself from a known git open source repo.

Answer (score 0):

In my system the problem was the empty space inside the path of install and how that is managed inside of the pc files.

A workaround is to edit the pc files  to change the prefix entry to the short path. In my system:

```
prefix=C:/PROGRA~1/Mono
```

instead of

```
prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
```